# How to call the element from a PHP object

Tags: php, phpword

I use the PHPWord package to load my *doc file.

The code:

```
<?php 
require_once './PHPWord/PHPWord.php';

$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('helloWorld.docx');

print_r($document);
?>
```

I want to get content from *doc by using the function "loadTemplate()".

The print print_r() are shown as below:

```
PHPWord_Template Object ( [_objZip:PHPWord_Template:private] => ZipArchive Object ( [status] => 0 [statusSys] => 0 [numFiles] => 12 [filename] => C:\xampp\htdocs\1510279872.docx [comment] => ) [_tempFileName:PHPWord_Template:private] => .\1510279872.docx [_documentXML:PHPWord_Template:private] => Hello world! Hello world! I am formatted. Hello world! I am formatted by a user defined style )
```

I want to get" Hello world! Hello world! I am formatted. Hello world! I am formatted by a user defined style", but I don't know how call it.

Comment: Check out the `SAMPLES` right there in the archive. 
   https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/develop/samples

Comment: I got the package from here [http://phpword.codeplex.com/](http://phpword.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Have a look at the `EXAMPLES` folder

Comment: you should get the latest version from the github link provided above. The codeplex version hasn't been updated/maintained in a long time (and the github version is continued based on the codeplex version).

Comment: Oh~right. I have already installed the latest version through your above link, but sill don't know how to read the *.doc content....